# Exact translation of "'round midnight"

Tags: traducción

How is the exact translation to Spanish of the phrase *'round midnight*?

Is it *por la madrugrada*?

Comment: "round midnight" isn't even an English phrase... Do you mean "Around midnight?"

Comment: Round=around the same....

Comment: Do you mean **'round midnight**, with the apostrophe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of "round midnight" is "Alrededor de la media noche" o "Alrededor de la medianoche".

The translation of "la madrugada" is like the famous band *Judas Priest* used to say......."Before de dawn". :-)

Comment: I think it should 'medianoche' instead of 'media noche'. The latter means 'half of the night'.

Comment: Thanks @tunic for the comment. I just checked and it can be spelled both ways. "Media noche" and "Medianoche" are both ok according to RAE  so I added that to my answer.  See http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=R3tGnihBrD6HboYOCc

Comment: There is a movie called *Round MIdnight* which was actually translated in Spanish as *Alrededor de la medianoche*.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre las 12 de la madrugada. 
Madrugada can be 1, 2,3,4,5 even 6 am, I understand midnight as 12

Comment: Good answer! I would upvote it if I could. Also, "sobre las 12 de la noche" is an alternative to "sobre las 12 de la madrugada" (when does "noche" end and "madrugada" start?); and even "sobre la medianoche" to keep the original phrasing.

Comment: Well, I understand 6am as morning rather than madrugada.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `por la medianoche` to keep with the contracted nature of *'round midnight*.

`Madrugada` is typically understood as the *wee hours of the morning*, but wouldn't generally include midnight.

(*Exact* translation is an oxymoron)